# Find the closest distance between points following a set of LineStrings

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have two datasets of Point coordinates (representing electrical installations) and would like to find the closest match between the two datasets following a given set of LineStrings (representing the cables). As an example let's take the following situation:

```
points1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry' : [Point(0,0), Point(3,3)]})
points3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry' : [Point(1,0), Point(4,4)]})
lines = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry' : [LineString([Point(0,0),Point(0,4)]),LineString([Point(0,4),Point(4,4)]), LineString([Point(2,4),Point(2,0)]),LineString([Point(1,0),Point(3,0), Point(3,3)])]})
```

[image]

Here we can see that red point (0,0) is closest to green point (4,4) when following the lines (distance 8) and red point (3,3) is closest to green point (1,0).

How can I automatically calculate the closest green point for each red point? The lines can sometimes be split into smaller segments like in the example.

Comment: You want rounting and graph thoery to do this kind of things. In python you have networkX

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Do you know how to transform this data to a graph where the points are nodes and the lines are the edges?